# Identity in cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology

Let $N^{4k+1}$ be a compact oriented manifold with boundary $i:M^{4k} \hookrightarrow N$. Suppose $c \in H^{4k}(N,A)$ for some abelian group $A$. I have to prove that $ \langle i^*(c), [M]  \rangle =0 $. In order to do this I'd like to prove that 
$$ \langle i^*(c),[M] \rangle = \langle c, i_*[M] \rangle .$$
But why this identity is true? I denote with $[M] \in H_n(M)$ the fundalmental class and with $c$ an element in $H^n(M;A)$. Then how can I conclude my thesis?

Comment: the identity $\langle f^*c,r\rangle=\langle c,f_*r$ is true for any $f:X\to Y$ and any $c\in H^k(Y,A)$, $r\in H_k(X)$; it's true already for singular chains/cochains (to see that $i_*[M]=0$ use a triangulation of $N$)

Comment: @user8268 But why is it true?

Comment: because it's the *definition* of $f^*$

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to write everything out explicitly here;

$$<i^*(c),y> = i^*(c)(y) = c(i(y)) = c(i_*(y)) = <c,i_*(y)> $$

Be careful to understand what is going on at each step.